# Text and Images in Column - align image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two or more columns with an image + text flow.

Image size could be `50` to `400px`, text from 1 line to 2 paragraphs

```
+---+
|   | +---+ 
|   | |   |
+---+ +---+
text  text
text  text
text
text
```

Is it possible using flex to align about the bottom of the images without using js?

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { line-height: 1.5; }

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap row;
  max-width: 60rem;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 33.33333%;
  padding-right: .5rem;
  padding-left: .5rem;
}

.col-img {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.col-content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="col-img">
      <img src="//placehold.it/600x200">
    </div>
    <div class="col-content">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Tousled cronut twee echo park la croix, church-key readymade wayfarers flexitarian mustache ethical semiotics microdosing cliche quinoa</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="col-img">
      <img src="//placehold.it/600x300">
    </div>
    <div class="col-content">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Tousled cronut twee echo park la croix, church-key readymade wayfarers flexitarian mustache ethical semiotics microdosing cliche quinoa</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="col-img">
      <img src="//placehold.it/600x400">
    </div>
    <div class="col-content">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Tousled cronut twee echo park la croix, church-key readymade wayfarers flexitarian mustache ethical semiotics microdosing cliche quinoa</p>
      <p>Tousled cronut twee echo park la croix, church-key readymade wayfarers flexitarian mustache ethical semiotics microdosing cliche quinoa</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/87j37r81/

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far......

Comment: A simplified example might be helpful. Like, what markup do you have? You could provide that as a Stack Snippet.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce the issue **in the question itself**, preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/87j37r81/

Comment: And preferably error free: `.row { ... flex-wrap: wrap row ... }` should read: `.row { ... flex-wrap: wrap ... }` for the wrap to actually work. Then add `* { outline: 1px dashed }` to your CSS so you can see what your boxes are doing. Still not the answer you need, I know, that's why I am commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that to work you need to drop the `col` rule/markup and use the `order` property to group them.

And the reason it doesn't work with the `col` elements is because then the `row`'s can't *see* each other and won't be able to align vertical. 
 <sup><sub>**(unless you give `col-img` a fixed height, but I assume you don't want that)**</sub></sup>

That, together with `align-items: flex-end`, will give the expected result.

The `flex-basis` will make them take equal width and break line, and with the `order` you place the image first.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 60rem;
}

.col-img {
  flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: flex-end;
  order: -1;
}

.col-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.col-content {
  flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-img">
    <img src="//placehold.it/600x200">
  </div>
  <div class="col-content">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Tousled cronut twee echo park la croix, church-key readymade wayfarers flexitarian mustache ethical semiotics microdosing cliche quinoa</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-img">
    <img src="//placehold.it/600x300">
  </div>
  <div class="col-content">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Tousled cronut twee echo park la croix, church-key readymade wayfarers flexitarian mustache ethical semiotics microdosing cliche quinoa</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-img">
    <img src="//placehold.it/600x400">
  </div>
  <div class="col-content">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Tousled cronut twee echo park la croix, church-key readymade wayfarers flexitarian mustache ethical semiotics microdosing cliche quinoa</p>
    <p>Tousled cronut twee echo park la croix, church-key readymade wayfarers flexitarian mustache ethical semiotics microdosing cliche quinoa</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm as an example (didn't know about order: -1), but I'd opt not to simply remove the `col` construction to make it work and rather explain why the given structure does not work (or make it work as given), while your solution IS in fact "cleaner". (confused? welcome to my brain!)

Comment: @RenevanderLende Thanks ... added a reason why it can't be solve with the existing markup

Answer (score -1):

Try this? [Flexbox Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
div#imageContainer {
  height: 160px;  
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, posting a code, a link and a text saying _Try this?_  is a really bad answer.